# (Argus) Error EndOfFile and Error InvalidState during jetson nano camera opencv tests

Tags: python, opencv, camera, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

I'm trying to test out my Pi Camera on my Jetson Nano. Simple tests run smooth but running [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/) python code edited to have the videoCapture argument of a gstreamer_pipeline instead of just '0'. This code however, only works once. When closing it down, I get errors:

```
(Argus) Error EndOfFile: Unexpected error in reading socket (in src/rpc/socket/client/ClientSocketManager.cpp, function recvThreadCore(), line 266)
(Argus) Error EndOfFile: Receive worker failure, notifying 1 waiting threads (in src/rpc/socket/client/ClientSocketManager.cpp, function recvThreadCore(), line 357)
(Argus) Error InvalidState: Argus client is exiting with 1 outstanding client threads (in src/rpcsocket/client/ClientSocketManager.cpp, function recvThreadWrapper(), line 368)
(Argus) Error EndOfFile: Receiving thread terminated with error (in src/rpcsocket/client/ClientSocketManager.cpp, function recvThreadWrapper(), line 368)
(Argus) Error EndOfFile: Client thread received an error from socket (in src/rpcsocket/client/ClientSocketManager.cpp, function send(), line 145)
(Argus) Error EndOfFile: (propagating from src/rpc/socket/client/socketClientDIspatch.cpp, function dispatch(), line 87)
WARNING Argus: 5 client objects still exist during shutdown:
    547548506088 (0x7f4c0034a8)
    547554717136 (0x7f4c001660)
    547554717296 (0x7f4c001700)
    547554722384 (0x7f4c001860)
    547554723520 (0x7f4c003390)
```

Then afterwards I am unable to start the camera up any way I try, and the following error is shown every time on any code:

```
(Argus) Error FileOperationFailed: Connecting to nvargus-daemon failed: Connection refused (in src/rpc/socket/client/SocketClientDispatch.cpp, function openSocketConnection(), line 201)
(Argus) Error FileOperationFailed: Cannot create camera provider (in src/rpc/socket/client/SocketClientDispatch.cpp, function createCameraProvider(), line 102)
Error generated. /dvs/git/dirty/git-master_linux/multimedia/nvgstreamer/gst-nvarguscamera/gstnvarguscamerasrc.cpp, execute:515 Failed to create CameraProvider
```

If I restart the device, I can run all the camera codes I want again, until I run that code again.
As I look through it, I don't see what is needed to fix it. The camera is released, what else is needed?

Comment: One observation in the context of this problem, that might help some people: Instead of rebooting the system, it suffices to restart the nvargus-daemon by executing `sudo systemctl restart nvargus-daemon`. That does not tell us _why_ the daemon sometimes is not satisfied with the way we release a video capture. BTW, the link to your code is not so useful because there you have to enter your e-mail-address to access the source code, it seems.

Comment: Did not help.....